# Rails 4 Devise Routing Error on user action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, routes, rails-routing

I have Devise authentication setup and working, and I've redirected the user to the user's own show page immediately after sign up or login.  The user show page and user edit page can be accessed successfully in the browser at:

myapp.com/users/1 and
myapp.com/users/1/edit

since I've setup a Users Controller - Now I need to simply take the action in devise that normally occurs at myapp.com/users/edit

```
edit_user_registration GET /users/edit(.:format)  devise/registrations#edit
```

...which is essentially the edit user account functionality, and I need to make it occur instead at users/:id/edit.  When I access the users/1/edit page for my user and update the email or password and click 'update'...the url changes to myapp.com/users/update_account and I get the following error:

```
Unknown action
The action 'update' could not be found for UsersController
```

config/routes.rb

```
devise_for :users

  resources :users

  resources :users, only: [:edit] do
    collection do
      patch 'update'
    end
  end

  root                'static_pages#home'

  get '/users/:id', :to => 'users#show'
  get '/users/:id/edit', :to => 'users#edit'

  get '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help'
  get '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about'
```

rake routes provides:

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                    Controller#Action
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH  /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          devise/registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#destroy
                   users PATCH  /users/update(.:format)        users#update
                         GET    /users(.:format)               users#index
                         POST   /users(.:format)               users#create
                new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)           users#new
               edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)      users#edit
                    user GET    /users/:id(.:format)           users#show
                         PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)           users#update
                         PUT    /users/:id(.:format)           users#update
                         DELETE /users/:id(.:format)           users#destroy
                    root GET    /                              static_pages#home
                    help GET    /help(.:format)                static_pages#help
```

My Header Links to the user profile and account settings pages:

views/layouts/_navigation_links.html.erb

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
<div class="dropdown"">
  <li class="dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
   <%= current_user.email %>
   <span class="caret"></span>
  </li>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
         <li><%= link_to 'My Profile', user_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to 'Account Settings', edit_user_path %></li>
    <li><a href="#">Edit Profile</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><%= link_to 'Log out', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<% elsif %>
    <li><%= link_to "Sign Up", new_user_registration_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Sign In", new_user_session_path %></li>
<% end %>
```

My Users Controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def edit
    @user = current_user
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    if @user.update_with_password(user_params)
    # Sign in the user by passing validation in case their password changed
      sign_in @user, :bypass => true
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render "edit"
    end
  end

    private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)
    end

end
```

My Views/Users/Edit.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, "Edit user") %> 

  <div class="container middle">

    <!-- SideBar NEED TO REFACTOR TO A USER LAYOUT FILE -->
    <div class="sidebar col-md-3">
    </div>

    <div class="main-content col-md-9">

      <div class="main-breadcrumb">
        Some Content
      </div>

      <div class="section_header">
          <h3>Edit Account</h3>
      </div>

      <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="col-md-6">
        <%= form_for(@user, :url => { :action => "update" } ) do |f| %>

          <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :email %><br />
            <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
        </div>

         <div class="field">
           <%= f.label :password %> <i>(leave blank if you don't want to change it)</i><br />
           <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
         </div>

        <div class="field">
           <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
           <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
        </div>

         <div class="field">
           <%= f.label :current_password %> <i>(we need your current password to confirm your changes)</i><br />
           <%= f.password_field :current_password, autocomplete: "off" %>
          </div>

          <div class="actions">
           <%= f.submit "Update" %>
          </div>
        <% end %>

        <h3>Cancel my account</h3>
         # I removed the devise 'cancel account' functionality for now

        <%= link_to "Back", :back %>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div><!-- end main content section -->

  </div><!-- end Container -->
```

Any help on how to fix this error would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to use `update_account` instead of a more standard `update`? As far as I can tell they'd do the same thing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser is sending `PATCH /users/update_account`, which looks like what you want. However, the first line in `rake routes` that matches is:

```
PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)  users#update
```

... which is *not* what you want.

You've got `resources :users` twice in config/routes.rb; you should only have it once. Try this:

```
resources :users do
  collection do
    patch 'update_account'
  end
end
```

This will generate all the standard routes for `users`, as your top line currently does, but also `/users/update_account` - I think *before* all the standard ones.

Comment: thanks Copeland...do you recommend i change all the update_account's back to just 'update' first?

Comment: Well, now that I look at it again, there is another difference, in that the `update_account` doesn't take an `:id` parameter and just loads the current user - which makes sense, so I think it's fine.

Comment: If you want some users to be able to edit other users' accounts, though, I'd have most of the work done in `#update`; then `#update_account` would just set `@user = current_user` and call `update` as a method rather than an action (while `#update` as an *action* would have a `before_filter` that found the user by ID).

Comment: cool makes sense.  i'm gonna mark that answer as correct but could you help me with one more weird thing.  All the code is update now, but when I edit my account at users/1/edit (using an incorrect current password)...the app redirects me to my show page @ users/1 instead of refreshing the edit page as i would've expected.   Can you tell why that would be?  thx

Comment: by incorrect i mean the validation should be failing (however I also removed the line from devise <%= devise_error_messages! %> because it was causing more issues.  (so i get no errors as i should for a failed validation then it redirects to show page instead of edit page).

Comment: `@user.update_with_password(user_params)` must be passing and returning `true`. Why that's happening would depend on how the method works and what the parameters are. I'm afraid I can't contribute much more than that at this stage.